# Как правильно подобрать селекторы?

Tags: c#

Я написал парсер с использованием AngleSharp.
Сайт для парсинга взят условно для теста.

Код

```
public async void Parser()
        {
            // *** HtmlLoader ***
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string currentUrl = "https://github.com/search?q=winform&type=Repositories";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl);
             string source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // результат парсинга 


            // HTML парсер, который доступен из "AngleSharp".
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            // Парсим
            var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);


            // *** Парсинг ***
            // var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item =>
            //         item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("post__title_link"));

            var fieldNameCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.col-12.col-md-8.pr-md-3 > h3");
            var fieldDescriptCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.col-12.col-md-8.pr-md-3 > p");            
            var fieldUpdateCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div > p > relative-time");            
            var fieldLangCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.text-gray.flex-auto.min-width-0"); 
            var fieldStarCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.pl-2.pl-md-0.text-right.flex-auto.min-width-0 > a");


            // Колличество
            int count = fieldNameCollect.Length;

            // Перебор элементов
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string fieldName = fieldNameCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldDescript = fieldDescriptCollect[i].TextContent;                
                string fieldUpdate = fieldUpdateCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldLang =  fieldLangCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldStar = fieldStarCollect[i].TextContent;

                ConnectDBAccess connectDBAccess = new ConnectDBAccess(tableName, pathDB);

                connectDBAccess.InsertRecord(fieldName, fieldDescript, fieldUpdate, fieldLang, fieldStar);
            }
```

У парсера есть проблемы:
1. Текст парсится с пробелами;
2. Некоторые части страницы не парсятся;

Вопросы.
1. Я получаю проблемы из-за неправильно подобранных селекторов?
2. Как устранить проблемы?
3. Правильно ли сделан парсер или можно его сделать более эффективным?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: от лишних пробелов можно избавиться при помощи [`Trim()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming)

Comment: @Bald работает...Я наверное в один вопрос встваил два и мне наверное нужно убрать `2. Некоторые части страницы не парсятся;`, чтобы вы могли оформить ответ?  Или, что делать со второй проблемой вы тоже знаете?

Comment: мне кажется что стоит в вопрос добавить что в итоге Вы хотите получить, сейчас это можно понять из кода парсера, но лучше вынести это явно

Comment: @Bald Не понимаю... Я наверное много хочу для одного вопроса... Мне нужно: 1. `убрать пробелы` - вы ответили; 2. `Почему не парсится "язык программирования" для записи id=14`?; 3. `Общие замечания(рекомендации)  по коду парсера`

Comment: У github есть [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). Лучше использовать его, а не парсить html.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov `github` взят условно, для теста работы с  `AngleSharp`

Comment: 2. А что вы ожидаете, если сам сайт выдает [пустое значение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Tyl.png)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Виноват... проморгал..

Comment: 3. Мне кажется не правильный подход получения коллекции имен, коллекции авторов, коллекции тегов и др. а потом все это склеивать по индексу (`fieldNameCollect[i]`). Что вы получите, если к примеру в коллекции имен на * имен больше, чем в других? Скорей всего ошибку... Получите сначала все div [элементы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3vO.png), а затем их перебирайте и делайте что надо с каждым.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не могли бы вы показать как это правильно сделать с использованием кода?

Comment: @eusataf Я не знаком с AngleSharp. Просто найдите сначала все элементы что я указал на скрине. Потом циклом пройдитесь и уже каждый разбивайте на имя, язык, автора итд.